# Android HttpsURLConnection trust certificate

Tags: java, android

I'm writing android application that interact with server. In my application I have several classes extends AsyncTask - one class for one request. Each class has URL and HttpURLConnection instance. Server address is: https:/myaddress.com (one '/' is missed). I keep it in application string resources. URLs I use in my classes looks like this: https:/myaddress.com/query1, https:/myaddres.com/query2...
Now I need to use Https, and before user will start interaction, I need to trust CA. 
First user's request is authentification (class Login).
If I put code below into Login class

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

URL url = new URL("https://myaddress.com/");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("KeepAlive", true);
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//posting content and handling response
finally {
    in.close();
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

is it enough to trust CA?
And can I be sure that my other HttpsURLConnection instances in other classes will use secure connection? 
According docs, I must use one HttpsURLConnection instance to one request, but it can use same underlying Socket for multiple request/response pairs. Is it true for my code? Or I don't need to call disconnect()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work this way (except maybe if your certificates are delivered by a native trusted CA but then you don't need to instanciate a new TrustManager).

Here is what we are using in our app :

```
  private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(Context context) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException
  {
    try
    {
      // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
      String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
      keyStore.load(null, null);

      AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

      for (String file : assetManager.list(""))
      {
        if (file.endsWith(".crt"))
        {
          CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
          InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(file));
          Certificate ca;
          try
          {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.info(TAG, "CA certificate [" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN() + "] added to truststore.");
          }
          finally
          {
            caInput.close();
          }
          keyStore.setCertificateEntry(file, ca);
        }
      }

      // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
      String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
      tmf.init(keyStore);
      return tmf.getTrustManagers();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      // TODO
      return null;
    }
  }
```

We are bundling the public keys of the root CA certificates.

> And can I be sure that my other HttpsURLConnection instances in other classes will use secure connection?

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Then all your new `HttpsURLConnection` will use this `SocketFactory`.

> Is it true for my code? Or I don't need to call disconnect()?

Just do a new `HttpsURLConnection` each time you need to do a request. The underlying `SocketFactory` which will be used by `HttpsURLConnection` handles the socket for you.
If you need to call the same URL multiple times in 10/20 seconds then don't `disconnect` but in the general case, you need to `disconnect` to free all underlying resources.

Comment: Thank you!
If my address has certificate signed by a native trusted CA, I can use only `SSLContext` and `SSLSocketFactory` without TrustManager and KeyStore.  When others, I need to create keystore, generate certificate using *.crt file, load it into my keystore, and use TrustManager. Is it right?

Comment: @user3533397 if your certificate is signed by a native trusted CA, then you shouldn't need to call `context.init`. That's already the default `TrustManager` which is used. You need to change the `SSLContext` if you are using untrusted certificates. On a side note, in our project, we have certificates signed by Comodo but we need to use a custom TrustManager because of a misconfigured CA certificate chain on the server side.

Comment: If we have native trusted CA, we can use only `HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();`, without `SSLSocketFactory`?

Comment: @user3533397 Yes it should work if your server is configured correctly